# Cannot send xlsx as attachment in Rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types, actionmailer, attachment-fu

I am trying to send an email containing a file attachment created by the user.

```
attachments[document.display_name] =  File.read(document.public_filename)
```

This works in most conditions (including .docx, but fails for .xlsx files with the error:

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I am using attachment_fu to upload the attachments, and delayed_job to defer sending the emails, however the file I am trying to attach looks ok, and I can open it successfully outside the application.

I also saw a suggestion to change the code as follows, but it does not seem to help:
 include an extra.

```
    attachments[document.display_name] =  { :content => File.read(document.public_filename), :transfer_encoding => :binary }
```

How can I make the code work for all attachment types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the mode or encoding to let it read the file as binary:

```
attachments[document.display_name] =  File.read(document.public_filename, :mode => 'rb')
```

or

```
attachments[document.display_name] =  File.read(document.public_filename, :encoding => 'BINARY')
```